# Proper Formatting and Procedures for Basic Data Entry and Manipulation in SAS

Tags: sas, linear-regression, data-entry

I have a data file that I am trying to import into SAS that looks something like the below:

WCM2B W C M 2 B M.B 2 18.4 12.3 g

WCM2B W C M 2 B M.B 2 19.2 12.3 g

WCM2B W C M 2 B S.P 2 19.5 DQ ('')

WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 17.7 10.7 g

WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 18.4 10.7 g

WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 17.6 10.8 g

WCM2B W C M 2 B Z.G 2 20.1 12.1 g

There are headings for each of these columns, some of which list categorical variables, and some of which do not.

My questions:

1) What is the proper code for ensuring a text file like this, delimited by spaces as shown above and with ~36 rows and 11 columns of data is properly formatted in SAS? How can I then perform operations on this data so that it comes up in the output window? Even the most basic procedure to do on some chosen infile would do. Ideally, if someone is feeling very generous I am trying to get an understanding of how to do regression analysis including analyzing residuals and standard statistics.

2) Do I need to change categorical variables into binary for it to properly analyze the data?

3) Are there any other issues with this data I'm missing that might make prevent it from working?

Thank you very much for your time.